# Help on QStackedWidget

Tags: qt, widget

I am using a QStackedWidget on my mainWindow. The firstPageWidget on stackedWidget contains 3 buttons. Now If I will press the first button on firstPage, I want the stackedWidget show the 2nd Page widget. Following are the details

I tried to connect like this in my mainwindow

```
connect(firstPageWidget->button1,SIGNAL(clicked()),stackWidget,SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```

Now I want to know how to pass the value of index number to stackWidget to set currentIndex?

If my question is not much clear please tell me I will explain more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to use [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) class:

```
QSignalMapper mapper = new QSignalMapper(); // don't forget to set the proper parent
mapper->setMapping(firstPageWidget->button1, 2); // 2 can be replaced with any int value
connect(firstPageWidget->button1, SIGNAL(clicked()), mapper, SLOT(map()));
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), stackWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of buttons you could use a QListWidget containing selectable Icons. QListWidget has a method called `QListWidget::currentItemChanged ( QListWidgetItem  * current, QListWidgetItem  * previous )`. I used that method in a program I wrote some time ago... There I wrote a function `on_change_widget( QListWidgetItem *current, QListWidgetItem *previous )` which I connected to the SIGNAL `currentItemChanged`:

```
connect( my_list_widget,
         SIGNAL(currentItemChanged(QListWidgetItem *, QListWidgetItem *)),
         this,
         SLOT(on_change_widget(QListWidgetItem *, QListWidgetItem *))
       );
```

That should do the trick.

You should have a look at the [Config Dialog Example](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/dialogs-configdialog.html), there they use the same method to swap widgets.

Of course you can use normal buttons too, in connection with the QSignalMapper chalup mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use QButtonGroup and set proper id to each button, then connect QButtonGroup signal `QButtonGroup::buttonClicked(int)` with stacked widget slot `QStackedWidget::setCurrentIndex(int)`